# Read a Jquery Data from File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

Hi im trying to Read json data and display data in nested table i have also give my expected result and also posted my script which i have tried.

**my Data.json**

```
 {"Data":[
      {
         "label":"node1",
         "color":"red",
         "children":[
            {
               "label":"vip1",
               "color":"red",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "label":"obj1",
                     "color":"gray",
                     "id":"539803eae4b0ffad82491508"
                  },
                  {
                     "label":"obj2",
                     "color":"green",
                     "id":"5395635ee4b071f136e4b691"
                  },
                  {
                     "label":"obj3",
                     "color":"green",
                     "id":"539803e4e4b0ffad82491507"
                  }
               ],
               "id":"53956358e4b071f136e4b690"
            },
            {
               "label":"vip2",
               "color":"blue",
               "id":"539803f2e4b0ffad82491509"
            }
         ],
         "id":"5395634ee4b071f136e4b68e"
      },
      {
         "label":"node2",
         "children":[
            {
               "label":"vip1",
               "color":"green",
               "id":"539803eae4b0ffad82491501"
            },
            {
               "label":"vip2",
               "color":"green",
               "id":"5395635ee4b071f136e4b694"
            }
         ],
         "id":"5395637fe4b071f136e4b692"
      },
      {
         "label":"node3",
         "color":"red",
         "children":[

         ],
         "id":"5395637fe4b071f136e4b692"
      }
   ]
}
```

**My script**

```
<script>
    $.getJSON( "data/widgetData.json", function( data ) {
    $('#widget').append('<table cellspacing="0" align="center" width="600" cellpadding="0" style=" border:3px solid black;">');
    var table = $('#widget').children();
    table.append( '<tr height="30" style="background-color:black"><td>Title</td></tr>' );
$.each(data.widgetData, function(index0, v) {
    //alert(v.color);


    table.append( '<tr height="180" style="background-color:'+v.color+'"><td>'+v.label+'</td></tr>' );

    $.each(v.children, function (index1, w) {
        //alert(w.label);
        table.append( '<tr height="180" style="background-color:'+w.color+'"><td>'+w.label+'</td></tr>' );

        $.each(w.children, function (index2, x) {
        // alert(x.label);
        });        
    });
});
table.append('</table>');
});

</script>
```

Please help me to achieve this and let me whats wrong with my script

Comment: There's no way those images could help us understand what you're trying to do. What would the raw tables look like?

Comment: @DelightedD0D sorry for the inconvenience please ignore the image my expectation was need to display the JSON data in HTML table with nested <TR> <TD>  based on JSON child node

Comment: I just mean that you could read the data and create any number of nested table combinations from it. IF you could show us the raw html table that you expect to end up with, that would really help us understand waht you need to do

Comment: @DelightedD0D
My expectation was - "Render the widget based on the json data .It can contain maximum of 3 column and rows can grow based on the data."

as per above mentioned .JSON file

Answer (score 1):

> what's wrong with my script?

1. In each of your `.each` callbacks you are doing exactly the same thing.
2. You should be using recursion instead of an unknown number of loops.
3. You are never checking to see if an object has a children property before calling `.each`. This results in `undefined` being passed to `.each` this will cause the following error: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` in the versions of jQuery I tested with.

> Please help me to achieve this

I am not going to try to make the result look like the page 2 image in your question. But here is the code cleaned up a bit, including two different ways to recurse over the JSON data.

This is a fixed version of the code provided in the question.

```
function ajaxResponseHandler(data) {
    var table = $('<table cellspacing="0" align="center" width="600" cellpadding="0" style=" border:3px solid black;">');
    $('#widget').append(table);

    table.append('<tr height="30" style="background-color:black"><td>Title</td></tr>');
    appendTr(table, data.widgetData);
}

// recurse over the data structure, 
// instead of writing an unknown number of loops within loops
function appendTr(table, data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
        table.append('<tr height="180" style="background-color:' + obj.color + ';"><td>' + obj.label + '</td></tr>');
        if (obj.children && obj.children.length) {
            appendTr(table, obj.children);
        }
    });
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p5v191a1/2/)

In this example the tables are nested:

```
function ajaxResponseHandler(data) {
    var table = $('<table cellspacing="0" align="center" width="600" cellpadding="0" style=" border:3px solid black;">'),
        tr = $('<tr height="30" style="background-color:black"></tr>'),
        td = $('<td>Title</td>');
    $('#widget').append(table);
    tr.append(td);
    table.append(tr);
    td.append(appendTr(data.widgetData))
}

function appendTr(data) {
    var table = $('<table style="border:1px solid white;width:100%">');
    $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
        var tr = $('<tr height="180" width="180" style="background-color:' + obj.color + ';"></tr>'),
            td = $('<td>' + obj.label + '</td>');
        tr.append(td);
        table.append(tr);
        if (obj.children && obj.children.length) {
            td.append(appendTr(obj.children));
        }
    });

    return table;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p5v191a1/3/)

Comment: Thanks robbmj,
Need to Display the obj1, obj2, obj3 in td tag..How & were to Change it..?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer :

```
function drawData(data,parent) { 
     $.each(data,function(index,item){
         var cell=$("<div><div>");
         cell.text(item.label);
         if(item.children) {
             drawData(item.children,cell);
         }
         parent.append(cell);
     });
}
```

You should be able to adapt this code to your needs